# mysql Replication and Point in time Recovery

Tags: mysql, recovery

I have a master and a slave mysql database (version 5.1). Is it possible to dump the database only on the slave side? If I do a dump with mysqldump I have a fulldump. Which files can I use for a point in time recovery? The relay logs?

Thanks and regards,
Martin

Comment: you can pull binlog from the master with mysqlbinlog from MySQL 5.6.

Or you can enable log_slave_updates and copy the binlog from the slave

Answer (score 1):

**Steps you should follow:**

a) Execute *flush logs;* on Slave server and Take a backup of slave server using `mysqldump` now new binary log will be created on slave server

b) Import the dump taken using `mysqldump` and after that using `mysqlbinlog` specify binlog file to read from till `point of recovery` time this will restore your slave status to a point you need to start with.